# PySerial presenting strange behavior in Python 3

Tags: python, pyserial

I have the following class (very basic) for communication with 3G modem through AT commands:

```
import serial
import time

class ATCommands(object):

    def __init__(self, port):
        self.ser = None
        self.port = port
        self.open()

    def open(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/'+ self.port, 115200, timeout=1)

    def sendCommand(self,command):
        self.ser.write(command.encode())
        data = self.ser.readline().strip()
        return data

    def getIMEI(self):
        IMEI = self.sendCommand("AT+CGSN\r")
        IMEI = self.sendCommand("AT+CGSN\r")
        return IMEI

    def getIMEIErro(self):
        IMEI = self.sendCommand("AT+CGSN\r")
        return IMEI

    def getIMEIErro2(self):
        self.ser.write("AT+CGSN\r".encode())
        data = self.ser.readline().strip()
        return data

    def __del__(self):
        self.ser.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(ATCommands('ttyUSB1').getIMEI()) #OK
    print(ATCommands('ttyUSB1').getIMEIErro()) #erro
    print(ATCommands('ttyUSB1').getIMEIErro2()) #erro
```

In the code above I have two strange things:

1. **getIMEI()** only works if I execute the statement **self.sendCommand("AT+CGSN\r")** twice in a row. **getIMEIErro()** shows that the IMEI is not returned a single command is sent.
2. If I run the command **self.ser.readline()** outside the method **sendCommand()** the code also does not work. **getIMEIErro2()** shows this error

Anyone know the reason for the errors?

PS: I'm using python 3 e pySerial 2.7

Comment: Are the results the same if you use `\n` as the terminating character instead of `\r`?

Comment: Yes, the same result.

Comment: What's the response when you send AT+CGSN through a serial terminal (eg Hyperterm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

- clear the buffer
- put sleeps to wait the baudrate to apply the commands to the modem
- always end your commands with \r\n

Something like (based of in my class in https://github.com/vhpanisa/misc  pyatapi.py):

```
def sendCommand(self,command):
    from time import sleep
    while self.ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        self.ser.read()
        sleep(0.1)

    # Maybe ascii encode not needed, just bytes convert

    self.ser.write(bytes(command+"\r\n", encoding='ascii'))
    sleep(0.5)
    data = []
    while self.ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        msg = self.ser.readline().strip()
        sleep(0.1) # Wait for buffer
        msg = msg.replace(b"\r",b"")
        msg = msg.replace(b"\n",b"")
        if msg != b"":
            data.append(str(msg, encoding='ascii'))

    return data
```